# sms html link in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have created a WebView, and i can't figure out how I can handle href links like sms: or tel:, etc..

Μy code does not work:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        boolean result;
        result = false;
        // for telephone
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url)));
            result = true;
        }



        // for SMS or message.
        if (url.startsWith("sms:")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            Intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            Intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code ?? working fine when i tested
just add this to it
if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            result = true;
        }

Comment: well, for me it is still not working, i'm still getting error webpage not available

Comment: can you post the full code ?

Comment: yes, http://pastebin.com/qfpQfdv8

Answer (score 0):

You set a default WebView client:

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Should be your own implementation:

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
```

(See the provided full code: http://pastebin.com/qfpQfdv8)

The rest should work just fine, your code does check correctly for sms and tel URIs.

Answer (score -3):

try like this,

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
        }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```